# bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./$.html`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bundle

I try to run my project but I get the following error: 
bundling failed:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./$.html` from `/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/core-js/modules/es5.js`: The module `./$.html` could not be found from `/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/core-js/modules/es5.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `$.html`
  * `/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/core-js/modules/$.html/index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:161:851)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:91:16)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
    at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
    at /Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:212:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
    at /Safee/sf-code/sf-safee-clients/sf-client-mobile/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:473
```

My bundle stuck in the middle .

What can be the issue?

Comment: Add the relevant minimal code relating to the problem. How are you using that, are you bundling with webpack? If so, add the relevant code from that

Comment: I am using iTerm. You can find some more code here: https://www.pastiebin.com/view/5b1ce20e8c1a4

Comment: Add the traceback to the question. Don't link to another site.

Comment: @HåkenLid I edited my question with exact error

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed my issue by going to `node_modules/core-js/modules/$.html.js` and duplicate + rename `$.html.js` to `$.html`

It will resolve your issue.

[image]

Comment: Cool, Worked for me too.
but its weird

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for opening this again, but today I have had the same issue, I was using expo and after installing formik. It was very weird because everything broke down rapidly. Today I spend all day, to find what the problem is, and after so much Google, this solution has worked!

Going to `node_modules/core-js/modules/$.html.js`, duplicate `$.html.js` and rename `$.html.js` to `$.html`

Maybe anyone has any idea, why it could have happened? Very strange, just want to prevent problems in the future. Could it be something related to formik? Or is it something else?

Rokas, Thanks!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30461509)